# All USB devices not properly detected on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I've had some issues with an improperly formatted USB key, and I uninstalled some USB drivers from the Device Manager thinking it would resolve the issue. But now, any USB device plugged in my computer would not be detected by my computer: it neither appears in the Explorer, nor in the Disk Manager. In the Device Manager, it appears under "Other Devices", and I can't update nor roll back its driver.

I already tried `DISM /restorehealth` and `sfc /scannow` without any success. I recently discovered my USB mouse doesn't work anymore either.

I also heard I could reset the drivers using `sysprep`, would it be useful in my case ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : added mention of sysprep

Comment: Do you remember what drivers you have uninstalled?

Comment: I think I uninstalled one under "Universal Serial Bus controllers" and another one from another category (maybe a storage one?) but I don't remember exactly

Comment: Is _System Restore_ enabled? Do you have any restore points?

Comment: I have a restore point from 11 days ago, but if there were another solution it would be better.

Comment: Restore points don't revert changes to your data, but just installed programs, system updates and drivers. Which devices are listed with problems in _Device Manager_?

Comment: Yup I know, I just don't want to reinstall some software I have installed since
For example when I plug in a USB mouse, it lists as "optical USB Mouse" under *other devices* in the Device Manager